# How to add SVG object in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, django, d3.js

I am following some examples of d3.js to plot graphs. For reference here is the [link](https://observablehq.com/@d3/line-chart).

Following is the code where I've used the `LineChart` function to build the plot. With Django as backend.

```
{% load static %}


<html>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>

<body> 
    <h1> Hello! </h1>
    <div id="chart"></div>
</body>


<script>

    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    const margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
        width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    const svg = d3.select("#chart")
      .append("chart")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);


    // Copyright 2021 Observable, Inc.
    // Released under the ISC license.
    // https://observablehq.com/@d3/line-chart
    function LineChart(data, {
    x = ([x]) => x, // given d in data, returns the (temporal) x-value
    y = ([, y]) => y, // given d in data, returns the (quantitative) y-value
    defined, // for gaps in data
    curve = d3.curveLinear, // method of interpolation between points
    marginTop = 20, // top margin, in pixels
    marginRight = 30, // right margin, in pixels
    marginBottom = 30, // bottom margin, in pixels
    marginLeft = 40, // left margin, in pixels
    width = 640, // outer width, in pixels
    height = 400, // outer height, in pixels
    xType = d3.scaleUtc, // the x-scale type
    xDomain, // [xmin, xmax]
    xRange = [marginLeft, width - marginRight], // [left, right]
    yType = d3.scaleLinear, // the y-scale type
    yDomain, // [ymin, ymax]
    yRange = [height - marginBottom, marginTop], // [bottom, top]
    yFormat, // a format specifier string for the y-axis
    yLabel, // a label for the y-axis
    color = "currentColor", // stroke color of line
    strokeLinecap = "round", // stroke line cap of the line
    strokeLinejoin = "round", // stroke line join of the line
    strokeWidth = 1.5, // stroke width of line, in pixels
    strokeOpacity = 1, // stroke opacity of line
    } = {}) {
    // Compute values.
    const X = d3.map(data, x);
    const Y = d3.map(data, y);
    const I = d3.range(X.length);
    if (defined === undefined) defined = (d, i) => !isNaN(X[i]) && !isNaN(Y[i]);
    const D = d3.map(data, defined);

    // Compute default domains.
    if (xDomain === undefined) xDomain = d3.extent(X);
    if (yDomain === undefined) yDomain = [0, d3.max(Y)];

    // Construct scales and axes.
    const xScale = xType(xDomain, xRange);
    const yScale = yType(yDomain, yRange);
    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0);
    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(height / 40, yFormat);

    // Construct a line generator.
    const line = d3.line()
        .defined(i => D[i])
        .curve(curve)
        .x(i => xScale(X[i]))
        .y(i => yScale(Y[i]));

    const svg = d3.create("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
        .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - marginBottom})`)
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${marginLeft},0)`)
        .call(yAxis)
        .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
        .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick line").clone()
            .attr("x2", width - marginLeft - marginRight)
            .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.1))
        .call(g => g.append("text")
            .attr("x", -marginLeft)
            .attr("y", 10)
            .attr("fill", "currentColor")
            .attr("text-anchor", "start")
            .text(yLabel));

    svg.append("path")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", color)
        .attr("stroke-width", strokeWidth)
        .attr("stroke-linecap", strokeLinecap)
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", strokeLinejoin)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", strokeOpacity)
        .attr("d", line(I));

    return svg.node();
    };

    var aapl = [
       {
         "Date": 1641168000000,
         "Close": 182.01
       },
       {
         "Date": 1641254400000,
         "Close": 179.7
       },
       {
         "Date": 1641168000000,
         "Close": 174.92
       },
    ];

    var chart = LineChart(aapl, {
        x: d => d.Date,
        y: d => d.Close,
        yLabel: "↑ Daily close ($)",
        width: 400,
        height: 500,
        color: "steelblue"
        })


</script>
</html>
```

I still learning javascript and specifically the d3.js library. I am unable to display the plot. What is wrong in the shared code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code. You are appending chart before it is created and also you need to use appendChild Method as you are returning node of the svg element.

d3 allows to append nodes created by d3.create by using appendChild. I have changed your code below to use appendChild to attach svg node to the chart div node.

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
const margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;



// Copyright 2021 Observable, Inc.
// Released under the ISC license.
// https://observablehq.com/@d3/line-chart
function LineChart(data, {
  x = ([x]) => x, // given d in data, returns the (temporal) x-value
  y = ([, y]) => y, // given d in data, returns the (quantitative) y-value
  defined, // for gaps in data
  curve = d3.curveLinear, // method of interpolation between points
  marginTop = 20, // top margin, in pixels
  marginRight = 30, // right margin, in pixels
  marginBottom = 30, // bottom margin, in pixels
  marginLeft = 40, // left margin, in pixels
  width = 640, // outer width, in pixels
  height = 400, // outer height, in pixels
  xType = d3.scaleUtc, // the x-scale type
  xDomain, // [xmin, xmax]
  xRange = [marginLeft, width - marginRight], // [left, right]
  yType = d3.scaleLinear, // the y-scale type
  yDomain, // [ymin, ymax]
  yRange = [height - marginBottom, marginTop], // [bottom, top]
  yFormat, // a format specifier string for the y-axis
  yLabel, // a label for the y-axis
  color = "currentColor", // stroke color of line
  strokeLinecap = "round", // stroke line cap of the line
  strokeLinejoin = "round", // stroke line join of the line
  strokeWidth = 1.5, // stroke width of line, in pixels
  strokeOpacity = 1, // stroke opacity of line
} = {}) {
  // Compute values.
  const X = d3.map(data, x);
  const Y = d3.map(data, y);
  const I = d3.range(X.length);
  if (defined === undefined) defined = (d, i) => !isNaN(X[i]) && !isNaN(Y[i]);
  const D = d3.map(data, defined);

  // Compute default domains.
  if (xDomain === undefined) xDomain = d3.extent(X);
  if (yDomain === undefined) yDomain = [0, d3.max(Y)];

  // Construct scales and axes.
  const xScale = xType(xDomain, xRange);
  const yScale = yType(yDomain, yRange);
  const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0);
  const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(height / 40, yFormat);

  // Construct a line generator.
  const line = d3.line()
    .defined(i => D[i])
    .curve(curve)
    .x(i => xScale(X[i]))
    .y(i => yScale(Y[i]));

  const svg = d3.create("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
    .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;");

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - marginBottom})`)
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${marginLeft},0)`)
    .call(yAxis)
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
    .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick line").clone()
      .attr("x2", width - marginLeft - marginRight)
      .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.1))
    .call(g => g.append("text")
      .attr("x", -marginLeft)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("fill", "currentColor")
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .text(yLabel));

  svg.append("path")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", color)
    .attr("stroke-width", strokeWidth)
    .attr("stroke-linecap", strokeLinecap)
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", strokeLinejoin)
    .attr("stroke-opacity", strokeOpacity)
    .attr("d", line(I));

  return svg.node();
}

var aapl = [{
    "Date": 1641168000000,
    "Close": 182.01
  },
  {
    "Date": 1641254400000,
    "Close": 179.7
  },
  {
    "Date": 1641168000000,
    "Close": 174.92
  },
];

var chart = LineChart(aapl, {
  x: d => d.Date,
  y: d => d.Close,
  yLabel: "↑ Daily close ($)",
  width: 400,
  height: 500,
  color: "steelblue"
})

// append the svg object to the body of the page
const svg = d3.select("#chart").node().appendChild(chart);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1> Hello! </h1>
  <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
```